# Как складывать и вычитать поступающие в БД числа от одного id?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, типы-данных

Имеется таблица в SQLite, есть столбец operation, нужно чтобы при функции 'Доход' число добавлялось к тому что там есть, и при функции 'Расходы' число от пользователя вычиталось. Как это можно реализовать в python sqlite3?
Моя запись в теле бота:

```
def get_sum(message):
if message.text == 'Доходы':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите сумму: ')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_oper)


def get_oper(message):
value = int(message.text)
operation = '+'

BotsBD.add_record(message.from_user.id, operation, value)
```

Моя запись в части БД(полагаю основная ошибка в ней):

```
 def add_record(self, users_id, operation, value):
    """Создаём запись о расходах/доходах"""
    self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `records` (`users_id`, `operation`, `value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                        (self.get_user_id(users_id),
                         operation == '+',
                         value))
    return self.conn.commit()
```

operation в таблице SQLite имеет тип Boolean и не равно 0.

Comment: все правильно Вы делаете нужно добавлять в 2 колонки доход и расход (столбиком) потом почитать это можно запросом, либо одна колонка с `+` и `-` таким образом Вы сможете посчитать баланс за любой период, не стоит вычислять прямо в базе и хранить одно число

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как это вижу я:

1. Создаём таблицу, в ней столбцы - user_id, balance
2. Не добавляем значения, а изменяем их

Как это выглядит в коде:

```
def plus(self, user_id, amount):
    self.cursor.execute('UPDATE records SET balance = balance + ? WHERE user_id = ?', (amount, user_id))
    self.connection.commit()
#минус по аналогии, в запросе просто меняем знак
```

Важный нюанс! Нам нужно создать первую запись, для этого мы проверяем наличие записей в бд и создаём новую, если записи отсутствуют

```
def exists(self, user_id): #проверка наличия записей
    res=self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM records WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,)) 
    return bool(len(res.fetchall())

def add(self, user_id): #создание новой записи
    self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO records (user_id, balance) VALUES(?,?)', (user_id, 0))
    self.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Выглядит правильно, но теперь появилась другая ошибка: TypeError: plus() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'users_id' and 'amount'

Comment: Ну, вы передайте то функции число и id пользователя) функция должна вызываться так: {объект бд}.plus({id пользователя}, {число}), id пользователя может быть его Telegram id - message.from_user.id